# What is an impediment, and how to handle them and internal improvements in Scrum?

Tags: agile, scrum

What do you defines as an impediment? I know that Scrum say that and impediment is something that stop the team from performing the best it can. So basically it can be everything? But where goes the magical line where it becomes and internal improvement?

For example. We want to have more realistic test data in our databases, is that internal improvement or impediment? We as a team could try to solve it in the sprint along with the other stories directly, or we could say that it's an internal improvement that needs to be a story and go into the product backlog.

As I see it we have three options:
1. Handle all internal improvements as stories in the backlog and make the PO prioritize them.
2. Work with them along regular stories in the sprint.
3. Big things goes in as stories and small stuffs we can do directly in the sprint without it effecting the velocity much.

How do you handle this? We need tips and ideas on how we can do this :)

Comment: This might be better suited as a question here: http://pm.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I try to post over there then :)

Answer (score 7):

**What is an Impediment**
An impediment is anything holding the team back.  It's a very wide open category that can include things like:

- physical hardware limitations
- missing or poor tools
- personal conflicts
- missing skills on the team
- missing personal skills
- lack of influence or authority
- illness
- missing knowledge

We often focus on the obvious: tools and authority, but *more* often it's the intangible that holds a team back.  Things like team cohesiveness, knowledge, and experience.

**More realistic test data**
Don't get caught up categorizing the improvement as internal vs impediment.  Our goal is to embed improvement into the natural delivery process.  For that reason, my first inclination would be to say all impediments and improvements should be done in the context of delivering.  You want improvement to be reflected in the ability to deliver.  We want our outcomes to reflect reality.  Sometimes improvement efforts mean we temporarily lower velocity in the name of future increases.  Sometimes we even permanently lower velocity in the name of quality.

I would suggest finding incremental ways you can get to your proposed end state and implement a little bit of it each time you touch that area, each sprint, and/or each time your prepare another test run (assuming it takes prep time - if not - fantastic!).

**Improvements on Backlog**
This is your choice and something you should discuss with your PO.  Understand that while the PO wants high quality and improved output from sprints, the backlog is meant to represent valuable features/requirements from the *user's* perspective - not yours.  For that reason, I would be hesitent to put improvement items on the backlog.  You should ALWAYS be improving with each backlog item.  Your PO may also balk at filling the backlog with things they feel should be done as part of normal delivery.  Take it as a signal that this stuff is not directly valuable to the user, but a cost of delivering high quality value at a sustainable pace.